# unable to fetch data from Tableau API

Tags: python, rest, tableau-api

I am new to Python and REST API calling.
I am trying to fetch data from Tableau server using **tableau_api_lib** module.

I am able to eshtablised the connection (login) and logout function with the help of  https://github.com/divinorum-webb/tableau-api-lib/blob/master/src/tableau_api_lib/tableau_server_connection.py .

I have gone through [Tableau REST documentation](https://help.tableau.com/current/api/rest_api/en-us/REST/rest_api_concepts_fundamentals.htm) also, but unable to understand how I can hit a API to get data from the server.

> For example :
> I have to fetch data from **historical_data** workbook which have has 21 sheets.

```
conn_obj = TableauServerConnection(tableau_config)
conn_obj.sign_in()

#API Calling
response = conn_obj.query_sites()
site_list = [(site['name'], site['id']) for site in response.json()['sites']['site']]

conn_obj.sign_out()
```

In tableau online, I am getting workbook data from https://tableau.xyz.net.com/#/workbooks/69478/views and sheets data from https://tableau.xyz.net.com/#/views/Historicaldata/sheet1, I have edited the link due to client privacy.

Comment: The REST API is not intended to fetch data within a published workbook but rather manage your server content. As it states in the link your posted: "Tableau Server provides an application programming interface (API) that lets you programmatically manage users, workbooks, data connections, and other resources on the server. By using the API, you can create users or import them from Active Directory, publish workbooks, create, view, and delete data sources, and perform other actions on the server."

Comment: There is an API endpoint to query a view's data, see https://help.tableau.com/current/api/rest_api/en-us/REST/rest_api_ref_workbooks_and_views.htm#query_view_data